# Fix mic in an ASUS F5-SL

Tags: asus, microphone, hda-intel

My first question!

I'm not able to get my internal mic to work properly. All I can hear is a lot of static and noise, plus barely my voice.

If I boost the sound static/noise volumes up as well.

My laptop is an ASUS F5-SL with a HDA SIS966 (ALC660-VD Analog) in Kubuntu 12.04 (64 bits).

I tried mixing volumes with alsamixer and installing alsa-hda-dkms with no success.

Answer (score 1):

try to run your program with pulseaudio suspended - like this:

pasuspender -- yourprogram

and record a sample.

If it works better, it might be a problem related to the pulseaudio-alsa communication.

Answer (score 0):

Well you see it may be the laptop have you got warranty on the laptop?

Or just follow the steps below:

1) Open the “Volume Control” panel.
2) In the “Volume Control” panel: “Edit” → “Preferences”.
3) In the “Volume Control Preferences” panel: tick 'Microphone' and 'Microphone Capture', and 'Capture'.
4) Close the “Volume Control Preferences” panel.
5) In the “Volume Control” panel, “Playback” tab: unmute the microphone.
6) In the “Volume Control” panel, “Recording” tab: enable audio recording from capture.

**REMEMBER!  I DO NOT TAKE RESPONSIBILITY FOR YOUR ACTIONS**

Comment: o_O

My internal mic works flawlessly under windows. It never did under GNU/Linux, however. Actually, I think a lot of people don't get mics to work under linux.

My laptop is around five years old and my mic never worked with any single distribution I tried, afaik. It didn't really bother me much as I don't really use it but since Steam is going to happen I'd like to speak with my friends as I play games (with teamspeak, for example). Or use voice chat in my laptop (I use my phone for that usually).

For the matter, an external mic doesn't work properly either.

Comment: Ok ill edit my answer but could you tick it and vote if it worked please?

Comment: I use KDE. I believe you're telling to go to some sort of Gnome/Unity control panel.

Anyways, I can record sound. Just not properly due to heavy static/noise.

Is there a way to reduce those?

Comment: Oh no you cant thats the problem you see either its your computer fan or the mic it self! There is a really professional solution for this but its too technical for me :D

Comment: Well. The mic works well on windows... :-(